# What are the available string matching algorithms besides Knuth-Morris-Pratt, Rabin-Karp and likes of it?

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching, knuth-morris-pratt, rabin-karp

What are the available string matching algorithms besides Knuth-Morris-Pratt, Rabin-Karp and likes of it?

Answer (score 8):

A well cited compendium of these algorithms can be found in:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.133.4896&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Included are the following algorithms:

```
Karp-Rabin 
Shift Or 
Morris-Pratt 
Knuth-Morris-Pratt
Simon 
Colussi 
Galil-Giancarlo 
Apostolico-Crochemore
Not So Naive 
Forward Dawg Matching  
Boyer-Moore 
Turbo-BM 
Apostolico-Giancarlo 
Reverse Colussi 
Horspool 
Quick Search 
Tuned Boyer-Moore
Zhu-Takaoka 
Berry-Ravindran 
Smith 
Raita 
Reverse Factor 
Turbo Reverse Factor 
Backward Oracle Matching
```

plus about 15 others.

BTW, you might want to clarify if you are also interested in string *similarity* algorithms (e.g., Levenshtein distance, etc), which are closely related, if you are indeed interested in that.

Comment: My eyes! My poor eyes! It's impossible to look at that file with Adobe Acrobat. Thanks a lot... I'm only sad it's unreadable (no, I'm not kidding)

Comment: If you zoom, it's not so bad.  There are other versions, including PostScript and HTML (which I think is useless, but YMMV):  http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=13525703680831471082&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&as_vis=1

Answer (score 3):

This page has good brief descriptions of many algorithms: http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Simone Faro and Thierry Lecroq provide a C implementation and references to 86 exact string matching algorithms on 
 ["String Matching Algorithms Research Tool"](http://www.dmi.unict.it/~faro/smart/algorithms.php) .

They also provide a framework to benchmark the string matching algorithms:

```
____________________________________________________________
Experimental results on englishTexts
Searching for a set of 200 patterns with length 128
Testing 5 algorithms

 - [1/5] BM ..................[OK]      0.88 ms       
 - [2/5] EPSM ................[OK]      0.38 ms       
 - [3/5] KMP .................[OK]      6.23 ms       
 - [4/5] KR ..................[OK]      1.84 ms       
 - [5/5] TW ..................[OK]      2.70 ms
```

**algorithms**

- BM = Boyer Moore (1977)
- EPSM = Exact Packed String Matching algorithm (2013)
- KMP = Knuth Morris-Pratt  (1977)
- KR = Karp Rabin (1987)
- TW = Two Way (1991)